# awk match multiple patterns in single match function

Tags: regex, shell, unix, awk

my csv file looks like this:

```
file1
        title1,title2
        car,21
        train,2015/10/02
        bus,hello
```

I want to remove all lines that have `title2 = 21`  and `title2 = 2015/10/02`

This is how i am doing it right now:

```
 cat file1|awk -F, '{if(match($2,"21")==0)print}'>a1
 cat a1|awk -F, '{if(match($2,"2015/10/02")==0)print}'>a2
```

final output

```
a2
            title1,title2
            bus,hello
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing it in 1 line so i dont generate so many unnecessary output files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use:

```
awk -F, '$2 != 21 && $2 != "2015/10/02"' aa
title1,title2
bus,hello
```

You don't need to call `match` if fields are already broken down by comma.

Comment: quick question, say for the date value, i have a few more like "2015/11/03" and so on where all start with "2015". How can i use regex to take out all lines that contain "2015" in $2?

Comment: You can then use: `awk -F, '$2 != 21 && $2 !~ /^2015\//' aa` Where `/^2015\//` is a regex to match all column 2 starting with `2015`

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F, '$2!~/^(21|2015\/11\/03)$/' file
```

to get rid of all 2015* dates:

```
awk -F, '$2!~/^(21|2015\/..\/..)$/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is enough? 
awk '!/21|2015/' file 
title1,title2 
bus,hello

Comment: No, it's not. Try it if the date was `2015/02/21`.